# MobilePush Send Log

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

Requirement is to create send logs for push messages however standard send logging functionality currently doesnt support mobile push.

What is the most efficient way to do this and how to retrieve jobid for push messages?

[Update 07-24-2017] Workaround (so far) is to use ampscript in every push message to write to a data extension that logs details of a push message.

Answer (score 2):

Schedule to generate daily push message detailed report. Run a daily automation to export it to a data extension. I've implemented this and working great without monitoring.

Comment: Can you expand on this a little?

Comment: Here are the detail steps - Mobile Push - Create report - Push Message Detailed Report - Create - Select your app and the timeframe(1 day, 30 days 7 days etc.) Then schedule this report to run every day. It gets saved to your FTP folder every day. Run an Automation Activity to import that file to a data extension daily. Schedule the automation to run daily. Now you will have all the push message attributes in a data extension. Feel free to contact me if you are struck.